# Assembly (intel): How does 'call address' relate to the resulting bytes in memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code, cheat-engine

Let's say I want to `call 5A31E0` and
the address of the next instruction would be `0CFF0016`.

When observing this inside the process memory it relates to
`E8 CA315BF3`. (little-endian)

How can I calculate this value (`CA315BF3`) by myself?
Is there anything else I am missing besides the address I want to call and the address of the next instruction?

edit:
with "relating" I am refering to the resulting machine code of an asm instruction.
For example: `mov ecx, 1B43000C` relates to `B9 0C00431B`, where `B9` is the opcode for `mov ecx` and `0C00431B` equals the value in little-endian.
However, `call` or `jmp` followed by a value does not look like that in machine code. (see example above).

Comment: "relates to", can you describe exactly what you mean here?

Comment: `call` is encoded as `call rel32`, relative to the *end* of the call instruction.  The rel32 is little-endian.  Read Intel's manuals.

Comment: `5A31E0 - 0CFF0016 = -ca4ce36 = f35b31ca` in two's complement, and the value you're seeing is precisely that in little-endian.